# Edit and Delete Data From Worksheet Without Generating Unique ID - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working with a project that needs to edit and delete data in the worksheet. So what's currently happening in the system is that, the userform has a listbox and textboxes. Whenever the user double clicks the row, the data will be fetched in different textboxes it belong.

So what I would like to happen is that whenever a command button named "Edit Data" is clicked, the manually entered data in the textboxes will be updated to the main worksheet database. Also, when a command button named "Delete Data" will be clicked, the entire row will be deleted.

So far, this is the code that I have modified that I have found in the internet, but it doesn't work. Because most of the codes that I found requires unique ID of each data row.

```
Private Sub edit_CB_Click()
'declare the variables

Dim DataSH As Worksheet
Dim erowa As Integer
Dim x As Integer
erowa = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.range("A:A"))
'error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set DataSH = Sheet1
'check for values
If Rep6.Value = "" Or Rep4.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "There is not data to edit"
Exit Sub
End If
'clear the listbox
lstEmployee.RowSource = ""

For x = 2 To erowa
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value = Me.Rep3.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "E").Value = Me.Rep2.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "F").Value = Me.Rep1.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "G").Value = Me.Rep6.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "H").Value = Me.Rep7.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "I").Value = Me.Rep8.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "P").Value = Me.Rep9.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "Q").Value = Me.Rep10.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "R").Value = Me.Rep4.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "S").Value = Me.Rep12.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "T").Value = Me.Rep5.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "U").Value = Me.Rep13.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "V").Value = Me.Rep14.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "W").Value = Me.Rep11.Text
Next
    Me.Rep3.Text = ""
'Protect all sheets
'Protect_All
'error block
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'Protect all sheets
'Protect_All
'show error information in a messagebox
MsgBox "An Error has Occurred " & vbCrLf & _
"The error number is: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please notify the administrator"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can determine the selected data's row by it's position in the listbox. See comments in the code for details.

Here is how you delete the row

> Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).Delete

Only toggle ScreenUpdating when working with large amounts of data

```
Private Sub edit_CB_Click()

    Dim x As Integer
    If IsNull(lstEmployee) Then
        MsgBox "There is Employee selected", vbInformation, "Action Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Rep6.Value = "" Or Rep4.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is not data to edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' If the listbox's Rowsource is a range then we can determine x by it's position in the listbox using ListIndex
    ' 1 is added to because the list starts at 0.  The actual offset is the Row of the first cell in the Rowsource + 1
    x = lstEmployee.ListIndex + 1

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        .Cells(x, "A").Value = Me.Rep3.Text
        .Cells(x, "E").Value = Me.Rep2.Text
        .Cells(x, "F").Value = Me.Rep1.Text
        .Cells(x, "G").Value = Me.Rep6.Text
        .Cells(x, "H").Value = Me.Rep7.Text
        .Cells(x, "I").Value = Me.Rep8.Text
        .Cells(x, "P").Value = Me.Rep9.Text
        .Cells(x, "Q").Value = Me.Rep10.Text
        .Cells(x, "R").Value = Me.Rep4.Text
        .Cells(x, "S").Value = Me.Rep12.Text
        .Cells(x, "T").Value = Me.Rep5.Text
        .Cells(x, "U").Value = Me.Rep13.Text
        .Cells(x, "V").Value = Me.Rep14.Text
        .Cells(x, "W").Value = Me.Rep11.Text

    End With
    Me.Rep3.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas for your response to my concern. Your codes work just perfectly fine but the thing is that, whenever the edit button is clicked, the edited data doesn't overwrite to the existing row but instead it just adds another row that contains the edited data. So, the question is that, how to overwrite those data to the existing row in the datasheet and in the listbox? Thank you so much again :)

Comment: Have  x = lstEmployee.ListIndex .  What is lstEmployee.RowSource ?